# Python cipher program - Too many members

Tags: python, list, matrix, encryption, members

I'm currently trying to make a cipher program, here is my code;

```
import string
import random

matrix = []
codedmessage = []
letter = "ABCDEF"

message = input("Enter message to be encoded:\n").upper().replace(' ', '')
print ('---MESSAGE---\n', message)

newlist = list(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
random.shuffle(newlist)

print ('---MATRIX---')

for x in range(0,len(newlist),6):
    matrix.append(list(newlist[x:x+6]))

for letter in message: 
   for y, vector in matrix: 
      for s, member in vector: 
          if letter == member:
            codedmessage.append(letter[x], letter[y])

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    print(matrix[i])
```

However, when I compile this I get the error;

> for y, vector in matrix:  ValueError: too many values to unpack
>   (expected 2)

Can anyone shed some light on this as to why it is happening and give a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but important to know for an aspiring Pythonista: Instead of `for i in range(len(matrix)): print(matrix[i])`, you can simply do `for item in matrix: print(item)`. Python is not C :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matrix.append(list(newlist[x:x+6]))
```

You append 6 element lists to `matrix`, but you try to unpack them into two variables later:

```
for y, vector in matrix:
```

The numbers have to match.

Currently you `matrix` looks like `[ [4,3,2,6,3,2], [2,1,6,8,9,2], ... ]`. How is python supposed to unpack one of the elements, for example `[4,3,2,6,3,2]` into `y` and `vector`? What should go where? (For possible solutions see the other answers, they were faster. I don't understand what behaviour is expected anyway.)

Also you cannot index a character:

```
codedmessage.append(letter[x], letter[y])
```

previously you assigned a single character to `letter`, here:

```
for letter in message:
```

because `message` is a string. You probably confuse names as you already have assigned a string to `letter` initially: `letter = "ABCDEF"` Probably you want to use two different names.

`append` does only take one argument, too. Again I don't know what you expect, but I guess it should be either `codedmessage.append([letter[x], letter[y]])` or `codedmessage += [letter[x], letter[y]]`.

I also highly doubt that you want to use `x` in `codedmessage.append(letter[x], letter[y])` because you only used `x` in another independent loop as iteration variable.

Answer (score 0):

Each element of `matrix` is a list of **six** items, so if you only provide **two** variable names on the left-hand side, Python doesn't know what to do with the other four.

However, you can (in Python 3) unpack back into a list like this:

```
>>> a, *b = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```